# Cannot find application variable to Application in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, casting

I want to use manual dependency injection and my intention is to use the Application class in a fragment for initializing objects, but Android studio cannot find a variable. I have defined the name of application in the manifest, but it says unresolved reference: application. Here is the snippet:

```
<application
    android:name=".di.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BasicsApp">

class App : Application() {
lateinit var appContainer: AppContainer
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    appContainer = AppContainer()
}
```

}

```
appContainer = (application as App).appContainer
```

Comment: Where do you invoke the last code? `application` is not "a variable". It is a property of `Activity`, `Service` and similar components, so it is available only from them.

Comment: I was invoking it in a Fragment

Comment: Then use `requireContext().applicationContext` or `requireActivity().application`. I'm not familiar with Android, so I'm not sure why and when context/activity may be null.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved the problem:

```
appContainer = (requireActivity().application as App).appContainer
```